# login through designation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

i have a two login types one is simpleuser and other is admin ...one admin is default admin he  create accounts of other admins  and he assign desginations and departments also

login code

```
             if (users == 1)
                {
                    Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
                    Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;

                    Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

                    Response.Redirect("AdminOp.aspx");
                }
                else if (users == 2)
                {

                    Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
                    Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;


                    Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

                    Response.Redirect("upload.aspx");
                }
            }           
        catch
        {
            Label8.Text = "Incorrect User Name or Password";
        }
    }
```

1 is admin and 2 is user
when supervsior is login to their account then he see menu where there is a options like this this is adminOp.aspx

```
                View Documents

            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="SuperVisor.aspx">
            <span>

                Approve Documents

            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

now when manager is login then how they access their page and able to see their menu because in above options there is only supervisor ...what about done this is manager?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, try explaining your self better, with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need a third user type.

If you want to show options only to a certain group, put it in a panel and hide it based on the user type.

```
<asp:Panel id="managerMenuOptions" visible="false">
 {options here}
</asp:Panel>
```

And in your codebehind, if your user type needs to see this menu, the code would be:

```
managerMenuOptions.Visible = true;
```

**EDIT**

The "right way" to do this is probably to create a user object with type and designation. Then check the value of the property you need to display what you need to in your UI.

Then you could check:

```
user.Type == 1
user.Designation = "manager"
```

The other thing you can do - sometimes the "right way" isn't viable for one reason or another - is create a variable that you store the designation in, and then use that to drive whether you show the options or not. It would do the same thing, only without an object.

Either way the concept is the same. You need to store the value you want to check somewhere so it's there when you need it.

Comment: there is only two user types 1 is admin and ther is user  ....manager, supervisor and director is desgination types  ...how i manage it..???

Comment: Are these other types designated in your user object? We should really see your user object code to effectively help you out.

Comment: there is another table designation and in this manager,supervsior and director desgination types in table